# How to download supported X.org version to be accepted by AMD installer?

Tags: drivers, 20.04, graphics, amd-graphics

I got new AMD videocard inside my Ubuntu box and it's using the default open source driver
which still gives me rendering issues here and there.

`lshw -c video` revealed that the card is Radeon HD 8870M / R9 M270X
I found relevant driver on AMD's download page and pulled the driver.

When I ran the installer it pushed back with:

```
error: Detected X Server version 'XServer 1.20.11_64a' is not supported. Supported versions are X.Org 6.9 or later, up to XServer 1.10

Installation will not proceed.
```

How can I upgrade the XServer ? I tried to run `sudo apt upgrade -y` but that didn't cut it.

It's running Ubuntu 20.04 up-to-date. Kernel version is 5.11.0-36-generic

Thank you.

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version and your kernel version? Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1365741/edit) your question.

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04 up-to-date. Kernel version is 5.11.0-36-generic

Comment: New card [from 2013 year](https://www.notebookcheck.net/AMD-Radeon-HD-8870M.86798.0.html) should work with open-source default drivers.

Comment: It "works" but I'm experiencing rendering issues. Like monitor freezes when I open up Firefox or freezes when I work with different windows. Plus proprietary driver often performs better.

Comment: There is no way to install AMD's old Catalist driver on 20.04. You'll have to downgrade half the system, which isn't practical or feasible.

Comment: Well my computer reboots every time I put on YouTube video with higher quality. Obviously the default Verde driver isn't good enough to handle basic video processing crashes and reboots computer.

Comment: Right now I have only 2 options. Either find a way to make Ubuntu utilize the videocard or switch to Windows 10.

Comment: Are you sure that hardware is working correctly? Which temperatures do you have for GPU in Xsensors or `sensors`? How fresh is thermal grease and how much dust do you have in cooling system?

Comment: I can confirm that videocard is working fine. I have it now working under W10 and the videocard is working fine. I'm just sorry I couldn't get it to work in Ubuntu.

Comment: It would be helpful if someone who's got same AMD chipset reported that he's got it working on Ubuntu. I don't mind 18.04, 20 or 21 as long as the os can use it.